# calling callback from another file? node js express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

why i can't getting callback as a record? must as a field('id')
ss : https://prnt.sc/ju4xb2

result reading as data row[0] from DAO

how i getting data from record ex: '0001' ? please help thankful

DAO

```
    var executeQuery = function(query,callback) {    
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: 'localhost',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'testt'
        });
        connection.connect();
        connection.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            connection.end();
            console.log("Here in Dao: " + rows[0].mobile_phone);
            callback(rows[0].mobile_phone);
        });
    };

    module.exports = {
        executeQuery: executeQuery
    };
```

Model

```
    var DAO = require('../lib/database.js');

    module.exports = {

    getuser : function(id,callback){

           var User =  DAO.executeQuery("select mobile_phone from ms_customer WHERE id = " + id, function(mobile_phone){
            // var json = JSON.stringify(User);
            console.log("Return from Dao = " +User);   
            callback(mobile_phone);
           });
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 

    test : function(req,res){
      var customerModel = require('../model/customer');
      customerModel.getuser('0001', function(mobile_phone){
        console.log("return from model_user = " + mobile_phone);
      });
    },
```

i always got error = 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column '0001' in 'where clause''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think error at query statement, please try this.

```
getuser : function(id,callback){

       var User =  DAO.executeQuery("select mobile_phone from ms_customer WHERE id = '" + id + "';", function(mobile_phone){
        // var json = JSON.stringify(User);
        console.log("Return from Dao = " +User);   
        callback(mobile_phone);
       });
    }
}
```

Comment: @Agunghallmanmaliki welcome, if it is solved, please accept answer! thx